# R stringr using subset

Tags: stringr

In R using the stringr package, how would you get only three occurrences of a letter within a word using str_subset?

Example- the letter "a" three times within a word

Results- banana and Canada

Comment: Hi, can you please add an example of input and output you like? would you input a world and known if it as a specific letter repeated 3 times (has_three_a("banana") # TRUE; has_three_a("apple") # FALSE); or do you want which letter(s), if any, are repeated three times (which_three_times("banana") # c("a"); which_three_times("apple") # NULL; which_three_times("abcccbaa") # c("a", "c")); or other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)

text <- c("Canada", "and", "banana", "baobab")

# Any character repeated three times: 
# 
# maybe something followed by a marked character, maybe followed by
# something different, followed by that character, maybe followed by 
# something different, followed by that character, maybe followed by
# something different
pattern <- "^.*(.)+.*\\1.*\\1.*$"

are_matching <- str_detect(text, pattern)
are_matching
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

words_extracted <- str_subset(text, pattern)
words_extracted
#> [1] "Canada" "banana" "baobab"

letter_repeated <- str_replace(words_extracted, pattern, "\\1")
letter_repeated
#> [1] "a" "a" "b"

# That give you the "last" repeated character
str_replace("baobaba", pattern, "\\1")
#> [1] "a"

# Note: If you want the first repeated character (if multiple), you
# should be lazy both at the initial optional set of character and at
# the first marked matching. (Not relevant for "detect" and "subset")
lazy_text <- c("bananan", "baobaba")
lazy_pattern <- "^.*?(.)+?.*\\1.*\\1.*$"
str_replace(lazy_text, pattern, "\\1")
#> [1] "n" "a"
str_replace(lazy_text, lazy_pattern, "\\1")
#> [1] "a" "b"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all words in which at least one letter appears exactly 3 times:

```
library(tidyverse)

vec <- "banana and Canada"
words <- vec %>% str_split(" ") %>% .[[1]] 
  
lgl_vec <- words %>% map_lgl(
  ~str_split(.x, "") %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    factor() %>% 
    summary() %>%
    "=="(3) %>%
    any()
  )

words[lgl_vec]

[1] "banana" "Canada"
```

Comment: What about using the str-subset function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_extract_all`:

```
input <- c("apple", "banana", "Canada")
regex <- "\\b[^\\WAa]*[Aa][^\\WAa]*[Aa][^\\WAa]*[Aa][^\\WAa]*\\b"
matches <- str_extract_all(input, regex)
```

### Demo